# junit not installed in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am using eclipse juno and have to run junit test cases but not able to find either junit perspective or junit in New option of File.
On searching Eclipse Market for junit ,I got JunitLoop,JunitHelper,QuickJunit,JunitFlux and JunitLaunchFixer,not sure which 1 to install.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should read the [Junit tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html)

Comment: I am using this tutorial only,in this it is mentioned that junit would be already installed in eclipse,but in mine it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can Go to MarketPlace and update the Latest JUNO. Or install a JUnit plugin available in MarketPlace.

Comment: Thanks Raghavendra...any idea which junit to install?
I am getting JunitLoop,JunitHelper,QuickJunit,JunitFlux and JunitLaunchFixer in MarketPlace.